# What's it called when you declare javascript in the <head>

Tags: javascript

What's it called when you declare javascript in the <head>? It's not external, and it's not inline...it's called something else. What is it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function message()
{
alert("This alert box was called with the onload event");
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="message()">
</body>
</html>
```

edit: google helped me find the word i was looking for - internal. i saw it used in the context of external/internal/inline css. is internal javascript an appropriate term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline is any javascript that's literally embedded in a page, whether it's in the head or body. If it's in an external file you include via `<script src="..."><script>`, then it's not inline anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It is inline JavaScript, it's just inline in the head, rather than inline in the body.